# why everytime readme file is being published?

Tags: github

I am struggling to figure out why the only thing I see on github page is the read me file.

I followed the instructions to publish to a github page here :
https://abhiverma04.github.io/dummycv/
my repo
https://github.com/abhiverma04/dummycv

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `readme.md` takes priority over `index.html`.

You can either make orphan `gh-page` branch and put all your files (except readme.md) to this branch. Or create `/docs` folder and copy all your files to the `/docs` folder except of `readme.md`. And after this action enable the relevant `source`setting in GitHub pages as it is described [in the GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rafael